# How to convert a List[A] into a List[B] using an implicit conversion

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have the following use case which occurs often in my code:

- A Collection[A]
- An implicit conversion A to B

and I want to obtain a collection of B. I can use implicitly like the following:

```
  case class Items(underlying:List[B])
  import B._
  def apply(a:List[A]):Items = {
    val listOfB= a.map {implicitly[A=>B]}
    Items(listOfB)
  }
```

What is the most elegant way to do that in Scala, maybe with the help of Scalaz of doing the same?

**Edit:** the goal of my question is to find an idiomatic way, a common approach among libraries/developers. In such a sense developing my own pimp-my-library solution is something I dislike, because other people writing my code would not know the existence of this conversion and would not use it, and they will rewrite their own. I favour using a library approach for this common functions and that's why I am wondering whether in Scalaz it exists such a feature.

Answer (score 14):

It's pretty straightforward if you know the types. First implicit conversion from `A` to `B`:

```
implicit def conversion(a: A): B = //...
```

then you need implicit conversion from `List[S]` to `List[T]` where `S` and `T` are arbitrary types for which implicit conversion from `S` to `T` exists:

```
implicit def convList[S, T](input: List[S])(implicit c: S => T): List[T] = 
   input map c
```

This should then work:

```
val listOfA: List[A] = //...
val listOfB: List[B] = listOfA
```

which is resolved by the compiler to:

```
val listOfB: List[B] = convList(listOfA)(conversion)
```

where `S` is `A` and `T` is `B`.

Comment: Is it somehow part of some standard libraries? I hate reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Edmondo1984: don't know, I wrote it from scratch just now, but I might be reinventing wheel as well. BTW read my answer again, I generified the solution so you need only one `convList` implicit conversion for any convertable types.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't use an implicit conversion here, but a view bound in the class:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
case class Bar(y: Int)
implicit def foo2Bar(foo: Foo) = Bar(foo.x)
case class Items[A <% Bar](xs: List[A]) {
  def apply(x: Int): Bar = xs(x)
}
```

You can now create an instance of `Items` with a list of `Foo` and internally use them, as if they were `Bar`s.

```
scala> Items(List(Foo(1)))
res8: Items[Foo] = Items(List(Foo(1)))

scala> res8(0)
res9: Bar = Bar(1)
```

**edit**:

Some clarification, on why I would not use an implicit conversion:

Implicit conversions can be dangerous, when they are in scope and accidentally convert things, that they shouldn't convert. I would always convert stuff explicitly or via view bounds, because then I can control it, also implicit conversion may shrink the size of your code, but also makes it harder to understand for others. I would only use implicit conversion for the 'extend my library' pattern.

**edit2**:

You could however add a method to the collection types, that does this conversion, if such a method is in scope:

```
trait Convertable[M[A], A] {
  def convertTo[B](implicit f: A => B): M[B]
}

implicit def list2Convertable[A](xs: List[A]) = new Convertable[List, A] {
  def convertTo[B](implicit f: A => B) = xs.map(f)
}

scala> implicit def int2String(x: Int) = x.toString
int2String: (x: Int)String

scala> List(1,2,3).convertTo[String]
res0: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Instead of using another implicit conversion here, I would probably use a typeclass instead, but I think you get the basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

Works starting with Scala 2.10:

```
implicit class ListOf[A](val list: List[A]) { 
  def of[B](implicit f: A => B): List[B] = list map f 
}
implicit def int2String(i: Int) = i.toString

// Usage
List(1,2,3).of[String]
```

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out it would be beneficial to specify that in the answer

Answer (score -1):

In my code, I'm using a more general version adapted from Tomasz' solution above which handles all `Traversable` instances

```
/** Implicit conversion for Traversable instances where the elements are convertable */
implicit def convTrav[S, T, I[S] <: Traversable[S]](input: I[S])(implicit c: S => T): I[T] =
  (input map c).asInstanceOf[I[T]]
```

(This is working for me, although I'm keen to know if any more experienced Scala programmers think this is a bad idea for any reason, apart from the usual caveats about implicit conversions)